# How to Convert Compressed Image File Formats to Uncompressed Image File Formats in PHP

Tags: php, image, compression

I have a question about image compression. Does anyone know how to uncompress images such as jpg, png and such into file formats such as tiff or bmp and vice versa via PHP or any other scripting language? Is there some library to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Sincerely,
Piotr.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which does this. However there are other libraries as [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) and [GraphicsMagick (GMagick)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php) that can do that as well.

The principle with any of these libraries is:

1. Open the picture
2. Save the picture in the format of your wish (TIFF, BMP, ...)

I would not recommend the GD library as it does not support the file-types you're asking for (TIFF, BMP).

Next to using libraries, you can invoke a command-line tool that will convert image files like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).

Answer (score -1):

The advantages of doing so are questionable. Compression works by losing some information in which case, the problem you're potentially trying to solve probably won't be solved. i.e. you'll still have dithering and the like.

Comment: what is your advice to accomplish this anyway?

Comment: More of a comment than answer

Comment: Not all compression is lossy.